# jquery mobile custom css only on reload

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have some jquery mobile pages with custom css but it takes only effect when i reload the page and not at first load.
The css file is called in all sites with:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mobile.kerger-mg.de/rezepte-suche/stylesheet/style.css" />`

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and your time.

Answer (score 0):

You must load all css the first time, in other words all pages must have the same inclusions,
don't forget that jqm is based on ajax navigation...

Answer (score 0):

try to link the page in question in this way:

```
<a href="PAGE_WITH_PROBLEM_CSS.html" rel="external">
```

in this way, the landing page (PAGE_WITH_PROBLEM_CSS.html) is reloaded.

:)